# How to display tags in plain htm inside ng-app of angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'me new to Angular JS. I wanted to know how to display the tags(or directive, expression etc.) written in my htm as such (present inside the ng-app).

e.g

```
<div ng-app="myExampleApp">
    <input type="text" ng-model="firstname"/>
    {{firstname}}
</div>
```

Now the textbox htm should be shown as such. (instead of a text box getting rendered). Please let me know how to escape them

One way is to use &lt and &gt and so on. But what about ng-model and how to prevent the expression from getting evaluated.

Comment: could you put it on http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ng-non-bindable directive will do this!. :)

e.g.

```
<div ng-app="myExampleApp">
    <input type="text" ng-model="firstname"/>
    <label ng-non-bindable="">{{firstname}}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle/plunk with this demo?